# Как реализовать простой счетчик без "global"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, globals

Я новичок в питоне.
Везде написано, что использование глобальных переменных в функциях это плохой тон и лучше так код не писать. 
Но как иначе реализовать такой функционал я не понимаю.

У меня есть переменная **`X`** и я хочу, чтобы каждый раз, когда происходил вызов определенной функции переменная **`X`** увеличивалась на единицу.

Для меня самым очевидным решением показалось такое:

```
count = 0

def counter():
    global count
    count += 1

def turn():
    counter()

turn()
print(count)
```

Но так как везде пишут про то, что "`global`" это моветон, хочу понять, как по-другому это реализовать?

Comment: Если коротко, то написать класс и создавать объект класса счетчика там где это необходимо.

Answer (score 6):

Простой декоратор-счетчик:

```
def call_counter(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapped.count += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapped.count = 0
    return wrapped
```

Сложнее, но так правильнее работать с декораторами - использовать [functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) (причина ниже в **PS.**
):

```
import functools

def call_counter(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapped.count += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapped.count = 0
    return wrapped
```

Использование:

```
@call_counter
def turn():
    pass

turn()
print(turn.count)
# 1

for _ in range(10):
    turn()

print(turn.count)
# 11
```

---

**PS.**

Причина в том, что декоратор, возвращая функцию не вернет ее `__name__` и `__doc__`, что может вредить для скриптов, что на это заточены.
Пример:

```
def call_counter(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapped.count += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapped.count = 0
    return wrapped


def call_counter_v2(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapped.count += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapped.count = 0
    return wrapped


@call_counter
def turn():
    """Это функция turn!"""


@call_counter_v2
def turn_v2():
    """Это функция turn_v2!"""

print(turn.__name__, turn.__doc__)
# wrapped None

print(turn_v2.__name__, turn_v2.__doc__)
# turn_v2 Это функция turn_v2!
```

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант:

```
class MyClass(object):
    count = 0

    def counter(self):
        self.count += 1
        return self.count
        

myClass = MyClass()
print(myClass.counter())
print(myClass.counter())
print(myClass.counter())
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно несколько "перевернуть" логику и засунуть переменную в атрибуты функции. Но это вариант не очень-то и лучше использования `global`.

```
def counter():
    counter.count += 1
counter.count = 0

def turn():
    counter()

turn()
print(counter.count)
```

Answer (score -1):

вот этот код будет добавлять по 1, и всего 5 строчек кода:

```
b = 1
while True:
  a = int(input('enter number:'))
  p = a + b
print(p)
```

Comment: а что у вас с отступами?